# Problems with a training task python if loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a loop to gather weather information and printing the days the weather is inside some presets. I am struggling as the print only uses the last input to list the days, and the first inputs are discarded.

After using updates from the comment, my code looks like this, but it is still not working properly, the code disregards the greater than and less than, and is printing the first 3 days. It also produces this error:   IndexError: string index out of range

```
week = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

rainlist = []
windlist = []
temperaturelist = []

for day in week:
    rain = input('What is the amount of rain today? ')
    rainlist.append(rain)

    wind = input('What is the current windspeed?  ')
    windlist.append(wind)

    temperature = input('What is the temperature? ')
    temperaturelist.append(temperature)

for idx, day in enumerate(week) : 
    if rain[idx] > '1':
        print(f'it is more than 1mm rain on {day} . It was  {rainlist[idx]}')
    if wind[idx] > '10':
        print(f'it is more than 10m/s of wind on {day}. It was  {windlist[idx]} m/s')     
    if temperature[idx] < '5':
        print(f'it was less than 5 degrees on {day}. It was {temperaturelist[idx]} degrees celsius')
```

Comment: you also need to change those rain[idx] to rainlist[idx] in your if statement too. rain[idx] is getting sub-string from rain, e.g. rain = "12", then rain[0] = "1" and rain[1] = "2", and there is no rain[2] so its raise IndexError. While rainlist[idx] get items from list, e.g. rainlist = ["1", "2"], then rain[0] = "1" and rain[1] = "2", it can also raise IndexError if your rainlist has fewer item than your week.

Comment: you need to change your input and comparison back to integer too. For string comparison, it is comparing the ascii value for the first element so for example, both "2" > "10" and "40" < "5" will return True because "2" > "1" and "4" < "5", while 2 > 10 and 40 < 5 will return False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index the wind, rain and temperature lists, you can use `enumerate` for that. Also use `format`for output:

```
for idx, day in enumerate(week) : 
    if rain[idx] > 1:
        print('it is more than 1mm rain on {}. It was {} mm'.format(day,
        rain[idx]))
    if wind[idx] > 10:
        print('it is more than 10m/s of wind on {}. It was \ 
        {} m/s'.format(day, wind[idx]))        
    if temperature[idx] < 5:
        print('it was less than 5 degrees on {}. It was {} degrees \
        celsius'.format(day, temperature[idx]))
```

Comment: In python 3-x it's prefer using `f'it is more than 1mm rain on {day} . It was  {rain[idx]}'` instead of `'something {}'.format(variable)`

Comment: This didnt wok, as i tried the edit the only output I got was:

it was less than 5 degrees on {day}. It was \{temperature[idx]} degrees \celsius
it is more than 1mm rain on {day} . It was  {rain[idx]}
it is more than 10m/s of wind on\ {day}. It was  {wind[idx]} m/s
it was less than 5 degrees on {day}. It was \{temperature[idx]} degrees \celsius
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/olenese/Downloads/engelsk regnliste.py", line 18, in <module>
    if rain[idx] > '1':
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @olense, I think the code here is slightly wrong, you should get item in list not variable, change `rain[idx]` to `rainlist[idx]` and so on. Also if you want to format string using Simon's method, note the `f` before the string that is `f"it is ... celsius"`

Comment: @MD98 I think str.format() is still fine in python 3-x but you have put the ) in wrong place, `print(str).format()` raise AttributeError, it should be `print(str.format())`

Comment: @adamkwm is right, thanks. Just corrected it. Should be an error easy to find if you just copied the code though. Also take care that the values you compare in the if-clauses are not strings. Strings are interpreted as text and cannot be compared to a numeric value. Make sure you dont put the numbers in ' '.